# Python dictionary ManuaLoa CO2

Tags: python, dictionary, numpy, formula, mean

I need some help with my python program. I have imported a .txt file and made a dictionary of it in an numpy array. The text file is a table of co2 meassures, one per month per year. I need to calculate a mean co2 value for each year in a formula (def annual_mean_co2). The "extract_complete_years" is a formula which exclude de incomplete years of meassurement.

This is my program so far:

```
data = np.loadtxt('MaunaLoa_CO2.txt', comments = '#')


def extract_complete_years(r):
    whole_year = data[10:-2, r]
    return whole_year



def read_MLdata(dittfilnavn):
    dictionary = {'years': extract_complete_years(0),\
            'months': extract_complete_years(1),\
            'decyears': extract_complete_years(2),\
            'co2': extract_complete_years(3),\
            'co2_interp': extract_complete_years(4),\
            'co2_trend': extract_complete_years(5),\
            'num_no_data': extract_complete_years(6)}
    return dictionary


def annual_mean_co2(MLdata):
```

I really hope somebody out there could help :-)

Comment: That is not much. What you have problem with in particular? You cannot expect people to do the whole work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to do something like:

```
def annual_mean_co2(MLdata):
    years = MLdata['years']
    co2 = MLdata['co2']
    y, _ = np.unique(years, return_inverse=True)
    co2_mean = np.empty(y.shape)
    for j in xrange(len(y)):
        co2_mean[j] = np.mean(co2[_ == j])
    return y, c02_mean
```

If, because you have only complete years, you are sure there will be the exact same number of entries for every year, you can vectorize the for loop as:

```
def annual_mean_co2(MLdata):
    years = MLdata['years']
    co2 = MLdata['co2']
    y, _ = np.unique(years, return_inverse=True)
    idx = np.argsort(_)
    co2_mean = co2[idx].reshape(len(y), -1)
    return y, np.mean(co2_mean, axis=1)
```